# How do I do this ? Time interval

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

there is a table.

```
(1, 'b', '2010-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-01-01 00:00:00'),
(1, 'z', '2010-02-01 00:00:00', '2015-01-01 00:00:00'),
```

How to do this:

```
(1, 'b', '2010-01-01 00:00:00', '2010-01-31 23:59:59'),
(1, 'z', '2010-02-01 00:00:00', '2015-01-01 00:00:00'),
(1, 'b', '2015-01-01 00:00:01', '2020-01-01 00:00:00');
```

Comment: You need to give us more description what you are expected result.

Comment: Pretty clear. One interval splits the other

Comment: Do the intervals always contained within each other or there might be an intersection?

Comment: Why does `z` supesedes `b` between '2010-02-01 00:00:00' and '2015-01-01 00:00:00'? Why not `b` supersedes `z`. In other words, what is so special about `z`?

Comment: The question needs clarification. Postgres version? Table definition? Is the "z" range always contained in the "b" range? (What if not?) Why are corner ranges excluded? (`'(2010-01-31 23:59:59, 2010-02-01 00:00:00)'` and `'(2015-01-01 00:00:00, 2015-01-01 00:00:01)'`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:
I ddint add the part when you take away a second from the enddate or add a second to the fromdate as I didnt see the logic there

```
with cte as
(
select 1 as a, 'b' as b, cast('2010-01-01 00:00:00'as date) as start_, cast('2020-01-01 00:00:00'as date) as end_
union select 1, 'z', '2010-02-01 00:00:00', '2015-01-01 00:00:00' 
),
cte2 as
(
select start_ as date_ from cte union select end_ from cte
),
cte3 as
(
select a, b, date_ from cte2 a inner join cte b on date_ between start_ and end_ 
),
final as
(
select a.a, a.b, a.date_ as startdate, 
case when a.b = lead(a.b)over(order by a.date_) then lead(a.date_)over(order by a.date_) end as enddate
from cte3 a 
) 
select * from final where enddate is not null order by startdate
```

Output:

```
a   b   startdate   enddate
1   b   2010-01-01  2010-02-01
1   z   2010-02-01  2015-01-01
1   b   2015-01-01  2020-01-01
```